# One div, top, middle and bottom background images

Tags: html, css, background

I would like to make a text box that has 3 backgrounds, the top, bottom and a general background image that repeats according to how much text there is.

So far I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/6pTje/29/

The background that needs to be repeated doesn't repeat because of the code. But when I take out the no-repeat and put it directly after the images, it doesn't seem to work.

```
#exampleA {
width: 660px;
height: 400px;
padding: 25px;
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/vt6xUmh.gif) left top no-repeat, url(http://i.imgur.com/Qn8iy0u.gif) left bottom no-repeat, url(http://i.imgur.com/8P2nGUp.gif) left top repeat-y; 
}
```

Can anyone take a look and see what I'm doing wrong? Or if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible? For the record I'd like it to scale so the more text there is the longer the box will get!

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6pTje/32/?

Comment: Alternatively: http://jsfiddle.net/6pTje/35/

Comment: ***a general background image that repeats according to how much text there is*** I guess this is fairly tricky, maybe involves some script.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, that's it! Thank you! Only question is how do I make it so that the repeating background stops and doesn't 'bleed over' the top and the bottom images? Is it because they are transparent that it does this? Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/6pTje/34/

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-y;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pTje/37/

```
background-position: left top, left bottom, 23px top;
```

Comment: Yes! That's nearly it. It's just the repeating image is aligned a bit too far to the left.